# Text position on canvas is different between Arabic and English when align text to right

Tags: html, canvas

I need to draw a text string in Arabic and English at a precise position on HTML5 canvas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//Draw rextangle.
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.rect(75,20,150,80);

//Text right align
ctx.font = "15px Arial";    
ctx.textAlign = "right";  

var x = 70 + 150 ; // the end of rectangle ( X + Rectangle Width )
ctx.fillText("text in english",x, 70);              
ctx.fillText("النص باللغه العربيه",x, 90);

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</html>
```

when text are in English it will start from x and don't move over or less than it even that when the text are in any long . But if text are in Arabic it will not start from specific x ! and every time the text will move over and less than x , why it's not static like English ?
try to write long or short text in Arabic and see what happens .
 [this me code in  JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tubdjvz/8/)
I Need Explain to Solve this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change direction per string, in canvas.

```
...
ctx.fillText("text in english",x, 70);
c.setAttribute('dir','rtl');
ctx.fillText("النص باللغه العربيه",x, 90);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ctx.direction = 'rtl';
```